Beta-reduction after delta-reduction in unfold tactic
According to the coq manual, the unfold tactic performs delta reduction on a definition, followed by several other reductions, including beta-reduction.
It seems that sometimes, to trigger beta-reduction after delta-reduction in unfold, you need to destruct an argument first.
For example, in the Lemma 'unfold_lemma' below, the first 'unfold myFunction' (commented out in the code), doesn't seem to trigger beta-reduction, while beta-reduction is performed after destruction of the argument t.
There is obviously something I don't understand with beta-reduction. Can someone help me clarify this point ?
Inductive tree : Type :=
| tree_cons : list tree -> tree.

Fixpoint andAll (ls: list bool) : bool :=
    match ls with
     | nil => true
     | cons h t => andb h (andAll t)
    end.

Definition isLeaf (t: tree) : bool :=
      match t with
      | tree_cons l => match l with
                    | nil => true
                    | x::rest => false
                  end
      end.
    
Definition isSpecial (t: tree) : bool :=
      match t with
        | tree_cons l => match l with
                      | nil => false
                      | x::rest => andAll (map isLeaf l)
                    end
      end.
    
Section flat_map_index.

      Variables A B : Type.
      Variable f    : nat -> A -> list B.
    
      Fixpoint flat_map_index (n:nat) (l:list A) : list B :=
          match l with
            | nil => nil
            | cons x t => (f n x)++(flat_map_index (S n) t)
          end.
      
End flat_map_index.
    
Fixpoint myFunction (l:list nat) (index:nat) (t: tree) : list (list nat) :=
    let l' := (l++[index]) in
    if (isSpecial t) then
         match l' with
          | [] => []
          | xx::rest => [rest]
        end
    else 
      match t with
        | tree_cons subtrees => flat_map_index (myFunction l') O subtrees
      end.

Lemma unfold_lemma: forall a,
      In [0] (myFunction [0] 0 a) -> isSpecial a = true. 
Proof.
  intro t.
  (* unfold myFunction. *)
  destruct t as [subtrees].
  unfold myFunction.
  fold myFunction.
  destruct (isSpecial (tree_cons subtrees)) eqn:HCase.
  + easy.
  + ... 


Can you add to your answer what proof state you expected to end up with and what happened instead?
(And can you also make sure that your code snipped works in an empty Coq buffer?)

Beta-reduction substitutes arguments into lambda abstractions. Lambda abstractions cannot be recursive. myFunction, being a Fixpoint, delta-reduces to a fix expression, which is distinct from a lambda abstraction (fun). fix expressions are evaluated using what Coq calls iota-reduction, not beta-reduction. Iota-reduction reduces the application of a fixpoint only when the decreasing argument of the fixpoint is headed by a constructor.
The distinction between iota- and beta-reduction ensures strong normalization: if fixpoints evaluated via ordinary beta-reduction, so they could expand when the decreasing argument was not a constructor, then you could expand the fixpoint inside itself forever. The system would still have weak normalization: for any term there would always be a reduction sequence that terminates with a value. The strong normalization property, that every reduction sequence terminates with a value, goes up in flames.
Some code demonstrating the above.
Definition plus_two n := S (S n).
Print plus_two. (* plus_two = fun n : nat => S (S n) *)
(* plus_two delta-reduces to a lambda abstraction written with fun. *)
Goal plus_two 2 = 4.
  cbv delta[plus_two]. (* (plus_two 2 = 4) delta-converts to ((fun n : nat => S (S n)) 2 = 4) *)
  Fail (progress cbv iota). (* iota-reduction does not apply here (cbv iota does nothing) *)
  cbv beta. (* but beta-reduction does produce 4 = 4 *)
  reflexivity.
Qed.
Goal forall n, plus_two n = S (S n).
  intros n.
  cbv delta.
  cbv beta. (* beta is allowed when the argument is a variable *)
  reflexivity.
Qed.

Fixpoint quux_two n := match n with | O => 2 | S n => S (quux_two n) end.
Print quux_two. (* quux_two = fix quux_two (n : nat) : nat := ... *)
(* Coq defines quux_two with a fix expression.
   Note how a fix expression names itself so it can be used in its own body.
   It is NOT a lambda abstraction! *)
Goal quux_two 2 = 4.
  cbv delta. (* now the goal contains an application of a fix expression *)
  Fail (progress cbv beta). (* beta reduction does nothing because there is no lambda abstraction *)
  cbv iota. (* iota reduction does work and unfolds one turn of the fixpoint, exposing a lambda. *)
  cbv beta.
  cbv iota. (* iota also handles match; this line actually does 2 iotas *)
  cbv beta.
  cbv iota. (* two iotas again *)
  cbv beta.
  cbv iota. (* only one iota (for the match) this time *)
  reflexivity.
Qed.
Goal forall n, quux_two n = S (S n).
  intros n.
  cbv delta.
  Fail (progress cbv beta iota).
  (* beta fails because there is no lambda.
     iota fails because the decreasing argument of the fix is not constructor-headed.
     the goal is actually in normal form; no reductions can apply.
     if you *could* expand quux_two inside itself... that would be bad, since there would be an infinite sequence of reductions.
     must proceed by some kind of case split on n, here induction. *)
  induction n as [ | n rec]. (* induction appears to do some simplifying  *)
  - reflexivity.
  - f_equal.
    exact rec.
Qed.

In your code, the decreasing argument of myFunction is the third one, t : tree. Therefore myFunction l index t will only reduce (that is, only take an iota-reduction after being delta-reduced) when t is headed by tree_cons.
Note that you can always explicitly prove that a fix expression is equal to its expansion. You just can't get Coq to automatically use such an equality during conversion.
Theorem quux_two_eqn (n : nat)
: quux_two n = match n with | O => 2 | S n => S (quux_two n) end.
Proof.
  destruct n; reflexivity.
Qed.

If you think it'd be helpful, you can write such a lemma for myFunction and use it instead of relying on conversion. I also hear the Equations plugin for Coq allows generating such lemmas automatically, though I've never used it.
(According to the documentation, unfold applies the specified delta-reduction and then all of the beta-, iota-, and zeta- (simplifies lets) reductions.)

Thank you for this detailed answer. I'm not sure that I fully understand the explanation about iota and beta-reduction limits to guarantee strong normalization. I though that, as the Fixpoint myFunction type checks, it is certain that there are no infinite reduction sequences, whatever strategy we use on the structural argument.

@FH35 That's only true if, like Coq does, you put a restriction on when fixpoints can reduce. If iota-reduction was not limited to when the argument was constructor-headed, consider: Definition F1 n r := match n with | O => I | S n => r n end. Fixpoint F n := F1 n F. Then the term F n delta-reduces to (fix F n := F1 n F) n. In Coq, this cannot reduce anymore. If the restriction on iota were removed, this could reduce to match n with | O => I | S n => (fix F n := F1 n F) n end. The new (fix F n := F1 n F) n inside this term could then reduce again, and this could go on forever.
